# Xamarin Android - How can I retrieve data from an async method

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

How can I please retrieve posts from the below async method? 
Because VS is giving an error saying “Await operator can only be used within an Async method”

```
class HomePage
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    List<Post> x = await GetTodoItemsAsync();

    public async Task<List<Post>> GetTodoItemsAsync()
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5000/api/posts");
        var posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Post>>(response);
        return posts;
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public ThumbnailImages thumbnail_images { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that this `GetTodoItemsAsync()` call:

```
List<Post> x = await GetTodoItemsAsync();
```

can't be called asynchronously when the `HomePage` class is being instantiated. I recommend moving that initialization code to another function where you call it explicitly in an asynchronous manner.

For further help, try reading this [Stephen Cleary blog post.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Await operator can only be used within an Async method

So you should have a method with the Asyn keywork

```
List<Post> x;
public HomePage(){
  GetList()
}

public async Task GetList(){
  x = await GetTodoItemsAsync();
}
```